# Want to save a file downloaded from firebase storage in to the device external storage in AndroidStudio Java

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, bitmap

Firstly I have uploaded an image or file to Firebase storage and then saved the link to firebase database. Now I want to share the image with other apps but it needs a local Uri (file//...), but my downloaded Uri is such like (https://....). So I want to save the image downloaded from storage yo the device's external storage and then to get a local url using bitmap...

i searched and get this but this does not work throwing exception:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imv;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;


    FirebaseFirestore firestore;

    GoogleSignInOptions gso;
    GoogleSignInClient gsc;

    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
    Bitmap bm;
    String extStorageDirectory;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);





        imv= findViewById(R.id.ff);

        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.xyz);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                        .getReference("trial")
                        .child("image")
                        .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                saveimagetoDeevice(snapshot.getValue(String.class));
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

                            }
                        });


            }
        });




    }

    private void saveimagetoDeevice(String url){




        bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
        bm = LoadImage(url, bmOptions);
        imv.setImageBitmap(bm);




        extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageState().toString();
        extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .toString();

        OutputStream outStream = null;

        String filename= System.currentTimeMillis()+".png";
        filename.replaceAll(":", ".");

        File path = new File("Pictures/"+"MediaVerse/");

        File file = new File(path, filename);

        File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "er.PNG");
        try {
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();

            Toast.makeText(this, "Saved",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }




    }

    private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String strURL) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        URL url = new URL(strURL);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();

            if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        return inputStream;
    }


    private Bitmap LoadImage(String URL, BitmapFactory.Options options) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
            if (in!=null){
                in.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e1.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }



}
```

its throwing this exception:

```
pictures/1685019507825.jpg: open failed: enoent (no such file or directory)
```

Please suggest something...

No idea what to do....

Comment: I have these permissions in manifest:   '
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
'

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?